# How to know which element/view in a fragment has focus

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

I have an activity with buttons and a tab which holds two fragments. I want a button in the activity to input text in the focussed edittext, which could be in either fragment.

So is there a way to find out which view has focus so that I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Activity.getCurrentFocus()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCurrentFocus())

```
View view = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
if (view instanceof EditText) {
    ((EditText)view).append("yourText");
}
```